# CSS Transition Ease not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want the icon in the center of the circle to fade in and grow when the checkbox is :checked.

The `span` around the `a` seems to be working nicely, and so it everything within the `a`.

For some reason, the transition: ease-in-out isn't animating the height/width/opacity - even if I set the property to `all`.

CODEPEN http://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/LVVpwX

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" name="menuToggle"/>
  <label for="menu-toggle"><span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble">
          <figure>3</figure></i></a></span><span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook">
          <figure>99+</figure></i></a></span><span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter">
          <figure>3</figure></i></a></span>
    <p>share</p>
  </label>
```

CSS

```
#menu-toggle + label span a {
  display: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3F7CAC;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


#menu-toggle:checked + label span a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #3F7CAC;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: With `all` you are animating the `display` property which is impossible.

Comment: even animating just 'opacity' doesn't seem to work

Comment: I mean even having `display` and `transition` in the same block is problematic…

Comment: "all" means you animate all animatable properties, display isn't, therefore there is no problem using all (besides animating everything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you toggle the display property, your animation won't work. If you need to hide the element, do so by setting aother property, like visibility. Just removing the display from the checked state solves the problem.

```
#menu-toggle + label span a {
  display: block; /* Just for styling */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3F7CAC;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


#menu-toggle:checked + label span a {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #3F7CAC;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 1;
}
```